# Cannot upload files that are in my local Google Drive to any website

Tags: 22.04, firefox, google-chrome, google-drive

In the pop-up window that appears to upload a file to any website, I cannot upload files that are in my google drive, I select them and they simply do not upload, any other file on my system can be uploaded.

When I put my google account in Ubuntu I got this "mounting" point named '/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=etc' but any file inside cannot be uploaded to any web.

I have tried in different browsers and different websites, such as uploading attachments to Gmail or with this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_file_upload_button

If I select a file from my system the file is uploaded without problems, but with all the files under this google drive path nothing happens, no error or freezing.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Thank you

Edit: I use google drive with the GNOME Online Accounts method

Comment: hi @javier-berna-garcia (1) Can you copy any file from your google drive to any other folder locally? (eg: `Downloads` folder) (2) Can you then upload the file from `Dowloads` folder? (3) Is it possible the files inside your google drive are just place holders and not actually downloded onto your computer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jags (1) Yes, I can copy and open the files from google drive without problems. (2) And yes, if I move the files to other folder in my system I can upload them normally. (3) The way this google drive "folder" works is very strange to me, but until now I was able to upload files from it so I don't know if this was a recent change and if it happens to other google drive users

Comment: Hi @Jags, after investigating a bit more I see that my method of using google drive (GNOME account) does not copy the files to the local filesystem. Now I have doubts about if I was able to upload files in the past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNOME Online Accounts with Google Drive does not allow uploading files to webs, to achieve this you can use [rclone](https://rclone.org/drive/) to mount and sincronize gdrive to a local mount point.

Here is a detalied guide to configure rclone for google drive:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/google-drive-guide#2-rclone